# How to force SVG aspect ratio in Firefox when drawing to canvas?*

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, canvas, svg

I'm trying to draw an SVG image onto a square canvas so that I can use it as a texture in ThreeJS:

```
canvas.width = 1024;
canvas.height = 1024;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

const texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
```

`img` is an image element in DOM that has svg data as the src.

**This works perfectly in Chrome**. The problem is that Firefox wants to maintain the aspect ratio of my original image and it won't stretch to cover the whole 1024x1024 canvas no matter what I try. Any ideas how to make it work also on Firefox?

SVG root:

`<svg width="100.000000" height="60.000000" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 100.000000 60.000000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`

Comment: can you show the svg markup too (only the root svg element)

Comment: Ok, I added that.

Comment: and you've got this problem only on the webgl texture or on the 2d canvas ?

Comment: On the 2d canvas. It seems that Chrome ignores completely the viewBox attribute. If I change it to `0 0 1024 1024` then it works also on Firefox. Maybe I'll just hack my img source data like this..

Comment: If I now understand this correctly, it's Chrome that is wrong here..

Comment: The more obvious thing to try would be a `preserveAspectRation="none"`

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` doesn't seem to change anything.